# How to iterate over realtime database in firebase function using typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in firebase cloud function. I am trying to iterate using code

```
export const onPlay = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const token = req.query.token
    let opponent: Player

    const playersRef = admin.database().ref("players")
    playersRef.once("value", snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(data => {
            opponent = data.val()
            if(token !== opponent.token){
                // return opponent
            }
        })
    })
    .then(opp=> {
        res.send("Hello from " + opp.name)
    })

})
```

But forEach must return boolean

```
forEach(action: (a: admin.database.DataSnapshot) => boolean): boolean
```

Comment: If you know the token of the opponent you're looking for, why don't you query for players with that token, rather than iterating everything at the `players` location?

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing a `return false;` at the end of the loop will suffice:

```
export const onPlay = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const token = req.query.token
let opponent: Player

const playersRef = admin.database().ref("players")

playersRef.once("value", snapshot => {

    snapshot.forEach(data => {

        opponent = data.val()

        if(token !== opponent.token)
        {
            // return opponent
        }

       return false; // <-----------
    });

}).then(opp=> {
    res.send("Hello from " + opp.name)
   });

});
```